# Validation of text field in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want to validate text field "Username" of the form as per below pasted code. The validation is to make the Username text field mandatory.

The problem which I am facing  here is the **text fields are not getting validated and `onclick` of submit button** it is directly moving to the next page **"index.html"** . Can someone suggest me how can I correct this in my below code? I want the **validation to happen first and then then if it is passing the validation, then the user can move to next page**.

**My Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
//validation for username to be a mandatory field
function ValidateContactForm()
{
    var name = document.ContactForm.userid;

    if (userid.value == "")
    {
        window.alert("Please enter your name.");
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    

</script>
<title>
Login page
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;text-align="center";font-size:30pt;
color:#00FF00;>
<strong>Welcome</strong>
</h1>
<form name="login">
Username: <input type="text" name="userid "/><br/>
Password: <input type="password " name="pswrd"/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

</form>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Test Input</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function testResults (form) {
var TestVar = form.submit();
}

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form method="post" action="index.html" name="ContactForm" onsubmit="return ValidateContactForm();">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: there is a syntex error.close your function ValidateContactForm()

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using custom JavaScript to validate the form (which shouldn't be relied on to actually validate the form as it can be bypassed), you can use the new HTML5 [`required`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp) attribute on your textbox to make it required on the client side.

Comment: Can you provide me with sample code as that can be helpful.How can I use the require attribute for my above code, can you share some demonstrations

Comment: @Dojo If you, where you have `<input type="text" name="userid"/>`, add the `required` attribute, making it `<input type="text" name="userid" required/>`, you won't have to do the checks. Also, please accept my or @Eric's answer if they have helped.

Comment: It is very strange its is not working for my code.This is what I replaced in my above code.<form name="login">
Username: <input type="text" name="userid" required /><br/>
Password: <input type="password " name="pswrd"/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
</form>. Can you see if its working at your end because it should work ,its strange.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="userid" />
<input type="password" id="pswrd" /> 


$("form").submit(event, function() {
    var userId = $("#userid");
    if (userId.val() == '') 
    {
        alert("Please enter your name.");
        userId.focus();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 validateForm = function () {
        return checkName();
    }

    function checkName() {
        var x = document.myForm;
        var input = x.name.value;
        var errMsgHolder = document.getElementById('nameErrMsg');
        if (input.length < 5) {
            errMsgHolder.innerHTML =
                'Please enter a name with at least 5 letters';
            return false;
        } else if (!(/^\S{3,}$/.test(input))) {
            errMsgHolder.innerHTML =
                'Name cannot contain whitespace';
            return false;
        }else if(!(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(input)))
        {
         errMsgHolder.innerHTML=
             'Only alphabets allowed'
        }
        else if(!(/^(?:(\w)(?!\1\1))+$/.test(input)))
        {
         errMsgHolder.innerHTML=
             'per 3 alphabets allowed'
        }
        else {
            errMsgHolder.innerHTML = '';
            return undefined;
        }       
        
    }
```

```css
.error {
    color: #E00000;
}
```

```html
   <form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
        First Name: <input type="text" id="name" /> <br />
        <span id="nameErrMsg" class="error"></span> <br />
        <!-- ... all your other stuff ... -->
    </form>
      <p>
        1.word should be atleast 5 letter<br>
        2.No space should be encountered<br>
        3.No numbers and special characters allowed<br>
        4.letters can be repeated upto 3(eg: aa is allowed aaa is not allowed)
      </p>
<button id="validateTestButton" value="Validate now" onclick="validateForm();">Validate now</button>
```